# Activating game object under conditions in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using c# in unity to create this basic game, and i have lots of objects with the tag 'cube' that i would like to appear when count >= 10, count is a variable previously declared and works properly and increments when game items are collected.
I have tried this many times in many ways but cannot seem to get it to work. This is the most recent try i had.

```
void WinText()
{
    other.gameObject.tag == "Cube";
        if (count >= 10)
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive(True);
        }
}
```

I get the error 'The name 'other' does not exist in current context' but similar code worked earlier in the code when doing the collecting game objects.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Pickup") 
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            count = count + 1;
            SetCountText();
            WinText ();
        }
    }
```

so i am not really sure how i am meant to be able to make the objects with the tag 'Cube' appear when a certain condition is met. I have looked around on the unity website for help on object destruction, i found some code that would be useful but they had no examples in C# only JavaScript
(http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks :)

Comment: WHat's your problem ? Is it worked or not worked ? did you get any error?

Comment: You would need to provide more detail. Also, you should add the Unity3d tag to this question.

Comment: it is not working no, im not really sure what i have to do. the error i have is: 'The name 'other' does not exist in current context'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, we essentially need to do 2 things. First we need the objects. Then we need a way to access them from the C# script, and call the `SetActive` method.

1. At the main menu, click on GameObject -> Create empty.
2. Name the game object something appropriate. Like CubesThatWillAppear.
3. At the main menu, click on GameObject -> Create Other -> Cube.
4. In your asset hierarchy view, drag the cube into the CubesThatWillAppear GameObject.
5. Go to your C# script that is linked to your player object.
6. Add a public property to reference the CubesThatWillAppear.

Like so:

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject cubes; // <--- We will reference this.
        // Other code
}
```

Now click on the player object and drag the CubesThatWillAppear into the Cubes property slot that you see. Go back to the C# script and call this code for the objects to appear when you want them to, I can't tell you in what method to place this, that depends on where you want them to appear.

```
cubes.SetActive(true);
```

When you want the cubes to disappear call this code:

```
cubes.SetActive(false);
```

Comment: thank you this worked perfectly :) this has been bugging me for days